# Monotone subgradients and convexity

Tags: convex-analysis

Convexity (for a differentiable function $f$) is equivalent to the condition that the following holds
$$
\langle \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y),\, x-y \rangle \geq 0.
$$
If $f$ is non-differentiable, is convexity equivalent to the same condition replaced with subgradients? It's clear that if $f$ is convex, then the condition holds by summing up subgradient inequalities, but for the other direction, does the subgradient $\partial f$ have to be a cyclically monotone map (see [here](https://regularize.wordpress.com/2018/06/04/subgradients-cyclical-monotonicity-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/?unapproved=17315&moderation-hash=91bd9ea8479271ed6cfcf97b19ec9d0c#comment-17315)), or is
$$
\langle \partial f(x) - \partial f(y),\, x-y \rangle \geq 0
$$
enough?

Comment: How do you define 'subgradient' for non-convex functions? Many non-convex functions do not have any subgradients, e.g. $x \mapsto -x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Only convex functions can have subgradients at arbitrary points. You can plot a simple non-convex function on a piece of paper and see why that is true